# How to show points as per unique category in a symbol layer without creating multiple layers?

Tags: azure-maps

I have a clustering enabled bubble layer.However upon zooming in, ***I want to show the points in unique colors as per the company property in the data. I'm achieving it via creating individual Symbol layers*** with unique colors and adding it to the map. I have more than 30 companies (more than 1000 points) so it adds 30 additional layers to satisfy the requirement upon zooming. **Does adding 30 layers to the map reduce the performance ? Or is there a better way to write a single data expression in the SymbolLayer options to solve this ?** Thanks

```
function addLayers() {
    const company = [...new Set(Data.map((i) => i.company))]; // creating a list of unique companies 
    
    // Looping through each company
    company.forEach((i) => { 
      let layerName = i + "Layer";
      let iconName = i + "Icon";
      let rColor = randomColor().hexString(); // get a random color
      
      map.imageSprite
        .createFromTemplate(iconName, "marker-flat", rColor, "#fff")
        .then(function () {
          map.layers.add(
            new atlas.layer.SymbolLayer(datasource, layerName, {
              filter: [
                "all",
                ["!", ["has", "point_count"]],
                ["==", ["get", "company"], i],
              ], //Filter out clustered points & unique company from this layer.
              iconOptions: { image: iconName, allowOverlap: false },
            })
          );

        });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a single layer with an expression will be much better for performance.

Here is a sample code block that loads 4 icons and then creates a symbol layer with an expression that selects the appropriate icon for a data point based on some property in the data point:

```
//Create an array of custom icon promises to load into the map. 
var iconPromises = [
    map.imageSprite.add('gas_station_icon', '../Common/images/icons/gas_station_pin.png'),
    map.imageSprite.add('grocery_store_icon', '../Common/images/icons/grocery_cart_pin.png'),
    map.imageSprite.add('restaurant_icon', '../Common/images/icons/restaurant_pin.png'),
    map.imageSprite.add('school_icon', '../Common/images/icons/school_pin.png'),
];

//Load all the custom image icons into the map resources.
Promise.all(iconPromises).then(function () {

    //Add a layer for rendering point data as symbols.
    map.layers.add(new atlas.layer.SymbolLayer(datasource, null, {
        iconOptions: {
            //Use a match expression to select the image icon based on the EntityType property of the data point.
            image: [
                'match',

                ['get', 'EntityType'],

                //For each entity type, specify the icon name to use.
                'Gas Station', 'gas_station_icon',
                'Grocery Store', 'grocery_store_icon',
                'Restaurant', 'restaurant_icon',
                'School', 'school_icon',

                //Default fallback icon.
                'marker-blue'
            ]
        }
    }));
});
```

Here is a working version of this code: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/?sample=Data-driven%20symbol%20icons